# Python - IndentationError

Tags: python

I need help in my code, I don't know why I'm getting *'IndentationError:unexpected unindent'* in the line 10 (def plus(self, v):), someone could help me?

```
class Vector(object):

    def __init__(self, coordinates):
        try:
            if not coordinates:
                raise ValueError
            self.coordinates = tuple(coordinates)
            self.dimension = len(coordinates)

    def plus(self, v):
        new_coordinates = [x + y for x, y in zip(self.coordinates, v.coordinates)]
        return Vector(new_coordinates)

    def __str__(self):
        return 'Vector: {}'.format(self.coordinates)


    def __eq__(self, v):
        return self.coordinates == v.coordinates

    v = Vector([8.218, -9.341])
    w = Vector([-1,129, 2.111])
    print (v.plus(w))
```

Comment: it'd help if you had copy/pasted it with the same indentation you have

Comment: Your `try` has no `except`. Why does it exist?

Comment: Are those methods supposed to be in the class body?

Comment: And why are you excluding 0-dimensional vectors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
class Vector(object):

    def __init__(self, coordinates):
        try:
            if not coordinates:
                raise ValueError
            self.coordinates = tuple(coordinates)
            self.dimension = len(coordinates)
        except:
            pass #TODO domething here

    def plus(self, v):
        new_coordinates = [x + y for x, y in zip(self.coordinates, v.coordinates)]
        return Vector(new_coordinates)

    def __str__(self):
        return 'Vector: {}'.format(self.coordinates)


    def __eq__(self, v):
        return self.coordinates == v.coordinates

v = Vector([8.218, -9.341])
w = Vector([-1,129, 2.111])
print (v.plus(w))
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `__init__` function, you are missing an `except` block. If you do not include this, your `try` statement is essentially useless. Make sure to add the `except` block to handle your `ValueError`!

Answer (score 0):

The error is coming from when you are calling `try` what you need to do is add and `except` to it like such:

```
try:
    if not coordinates:
            raise ValueError
        self.coordinates = tuple(coordinates)
        self.dimension = len(coordinates)
except:
    # do something here to handle error
```

> The try and except concept means that you are trying to perform an action in python but if an error occurs within the `try` scope then whatever is in the `except` scope will run.

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm gonna take a guess and say the code should look like this:

```
class Vector(object):
    def __init__(self, coordinates):
        try:
            if not coordinates:
                raise ValueError
            self.coordinates = tuple(coordinates)
            self.dimension = len(coordinates)
        except ValueError as e:
            pass
            # Code here?#

    def plus(self, v):
        new_coordinates = [x + y for x, y in zip(self.coordinates, v.coordinates)]
        return Vector(new_coordinates)

    def __str__(self):
        return 'Vector: {}'.format(self.coordinates)


    def __eq__(self, v):
        return self.coordinates == v.coordinates

if __name__ == '__main__':
    v = Vector([8.218, -9.341])
    w = Vector([-1,129, 2.111])
    print (v.plus(w))
```

The indentation in the code you provided was indeed wrong but i think the interpreter was expecting an 'except' statement(here just shown to pass but you should make it do something)

Answer (score 0):

See the [documentation on exceptions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions).

```
class Vector(object):
    def __init__(self, coordinates):
        # try: # every try must be paired with an 'except'
        if not coordinates:
            raise ValueError
        self.coordinates = tuple(coordinates)
        self.dimension = len(coordinates)

    def plus(self, v):
        new_coordinates = [x + y for x, y in zip(self.coordinates, v.coordinates)]
        return Vector(new_coordinates)

    def __str__(self):
        return 'Vector: {}'.format(self.coordinates)


    def __eq__(self, v):
        return self.coordinates == v.coordinates

v = Vector([8.218, -9.341])
w = Vector([-1,129, 2.111])
print (v.plus(w))
```